# Iron Router - window.location.href gets href of previous page

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

i am working on an app with Meteor that requires social shares. So I want to implement a social share on the single-post page.
I so I have this registered helper for facebook share:

```
Template.registerHelper('shareOnFacebookLink', function() {
    return 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?&u=' + window.location.href;
});
```

and in the **template**, I have this :

```
<a href="{{shareOnFacebookLink}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

The problem is that when i navigate from the homepage to the single-post (where the registered helper is needed), the `window.location.href` still shows the `href` of the previous page until I reload the the single-post page.

What i want is **how can I make the window.location.href get the href of the single-question page as soon as I land on it without having to refresh it?**

Thanks all

Comment: Have you tried `FlowRouter.current().path`? PS, you need to URL-encode it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Meteor.Router.path()` to get your current path.